# React prevState and increment object property +1 not work correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object

I have an object in my initial state, and when I press a button I want to increment that object's property + 1.

(it is a react native project)

My approach:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    myObject: {
      incrementCount: 0, // When i press button it should be increment + 1
      decrementCount: 0,
    }
  }
}

...

onPressButton = () => {
  this.setState(
    prevState => ({
        myObject: {
        ...prevState.myObject,
        incrementCount: this.state.myObject.incrementCount + 1,
      },
    }),
    console.log('TOTAL incrementCount: ', this.state.myObject.incrementCount),
  );
};
```

But when i press button, I get the following behavior:

```
console.log prints 0 for first click, 
1 for second click.
```

Object update happen after console log. But I'm using that in setState callback.

Comment: state in react may be asynchronous, add a calback to setState.

Comment: use ```incrementCount: prevState.incrementCount + 1```

Comment: @JuniusL Shouldn't it be `incrementCount: prevState.myObject.incrementCount + 1`?

Comment: Yes, it should be that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please pass a function as the callback instead of console log. From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) the callback should be a function but you are executing `console.log()` instead of passing a callback.

> setState(updater[, callback])

```
onPressButton = () => {
  this.setState(
    prevState => ({
      myObject: {
        ...prevState.myObject,
        incrementCount: prevState.myObject.incrementCount + 1
      }
    }),
    () =>
      console.log(
        "TOTAL incrementCount: ",
        this.state.myObject.incrementCount
      )
  );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "React",
      myObject: {
        incrementCount: 0, // When i press button it should be increment + 1
        decrementCount: 0
      }
    };
  }

  onPressButton = () => {
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({
        myObject: {
          ...prevState.myObject,
          incrementCount: prevState.myObject.incrementCount + 1
        }
      }),
      () =>
        console.log(
          "TOTAL incrementCount: ",
          this.state.myObject.incrementCount
        )
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.myObject.incrementCount}</p>
        <button onClick={this.onPressButton}>Increment</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
```